# SimpleITK.ImageFileWriter in Python has no method "SetImageIO" but C++ docs say it has

Tags: python-3.x, simpleitk

I'm using SimpleITK for Python and have created an empty image using NumPy as follows:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

pixels = np.zeros((64, 64))
image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(pixels)
```

Then, when I try to write the image to file in NIFTI format it complains that it cannot find the method "SetImageIO" on the ImageFileWriter object.

```
write = sitk.ImageFileWriter()
write.SetFileName('hello.nii.gz')
write.SetImageIO('NiftiImageIO')
write.Execute(image)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'ImageFileWriter' object has no attribute 'SetImageIO'
```

Does anybody know why this is? The C++ docs clearly mention a method "SetImageIO" for ImageFileWriter.

Thanks, Ralph

Comment: What version of SimpleITK do you have installed? This was a new feature with 1.2.

Comment: Good reminder, thnx. I have version 1.1.0. That probably explains the issue :)

Comment: Jep that was it, thnx!

Comment: I copied my request for more information to an answer, so that we can have an proper answer for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SimpleITK documentation is sorely lacking, and not all C++ library functions are available in the python package, which complicates a few more things.

However,

`sitk.WriteImage(image, "hello.nii.gz")`

Will automatically infer the filetype from the string.

Answer (score 3):

What version of SimpleITK do you have installed?

This is a new feature with 1.2, so if you have an older version the method will not be available.

Comment: I was using version 1.1.0 so that was indeed the issue.